# Формат даты с часовым поясом в moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

У меня есть дата в формате "Fri, 30 Nov 2018 16:00:00 -0500". Мне нужно ее отформатировать как "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm A". Можно, но не обязательно использовать moment.js

Пробую в консоли:

> moment("Fri, 30 Nov 2018 16:00:00 -0500").format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm A")

Результат:

> "12/01/2018 01:00 AM"

Ожидаемый результат - "11/30/2018 16:00 PM"

В то же время, такое выражение отрабатывает как я и ожидаю.

> moment.utc("Fri, 30 Nov 2018 16:00:00 -0500").format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm A")

Результат

> "11/30/2018 21:00 PM"

Как вообще этот moment.js работает с таймзонами?

Comment: Как можно ответить на этот вопрос не зная, в каком часовом поясе ты находишься?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, можно вручную указывать utcOffset

> moment.utc("Fri, 30 Nov 2018 16:00:00 -0500").utcOffset("-0500").format("MM/DD/YYYY H:mm A")

Или так

> moment("Fri, 30 Nov 2018 16:00:00 -0500").utcOffset("-0500").format("MM/DD/YYYY H:mm A")

Тогда

> "11/30/2018 16:00 PM"